# radial Gradient banding issue

Tags: css

I used a css generator to create

```
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(49,35,174,1) 0%, rgba(125,72,195,1) 50%, rgba(125,72,195,1) 50%, rgba(201,109,215,1) 100%);
```

It is not displaying correctly. The gradient is rendering as stripes of the two colors. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What browser are you using?  That makes a purplish radial gradient in Safari and should work in all modern browsers.  https://jsfiddle.net/x2wv5e1b/

Comment: Thats exactly what I want and its not displaying like that in Chrome.

Comment: Did you open that fiddle in chrome?  Because it displays correctly for me in Chrome 48.  Do you have an old version?  It's possible you have something else wrong with your css.  What other css is defined for this element?

Comment: Yep, I open it in chrome 48 as well.

Comment: And when you opened the jsfiddle link in Chrome, did it look as expected?

Comment: I hadn't defined the html height and width. Works now. Thanks Barbara!